# Android OpenErp Search Request XMLRPC

Tags: android, xml-rpc, odoo

I am working on an android application which is able to connect with an openerp server and retrive the userid and also the individual fields of the different contacts of that user.

below is the code on the things i have done so far

```
   public int Search()
   {

           searchClient = new XMLRPCClient("http://"+lp.HOST+":"+lp.IN_PORT+lp.URL_XML+lp.URL_OBJECT);

           try
           {
                   record = (Array[]) searchClient.call("search",lp.DB_NAME, lp.uid1, lp.PASSWORD, "res.partnet.contact","execute", arguments);

           }
           catch(Exception e)
           {
                   Log.i("------------------ CONNECTION FAILED Search", e.toString());
           }

           return 0;
   }
```

i appreciate the help given

Thank you,

Comment: What are you asking? I don't see any question here.

Answer (score 2):

try to interchange the position of method `search` and `execute`.The method `execute` must be given before `search`.Also try  `searchClient.callEx` instead call only like you do it above!

```
record = (Array[]) searchClient.callEx("execute",lp.DB_NAME, lp.uid1, lp.PASSWORD, "res.partnet.contact","search", arguments);
```

Comment: Is that working for you? I am using this arr = (Array[]) client.call("execute", "openerp", "admin",
     "password","product.product", "search"); where arr is Array[] arr. But it is returning me a html file